# Terminal Commands by java

Tags: java, linux

I am developing a web system in java, servlet and jsp.

I have a client CRUD ... when a new client is created I need to create a new database for it (tied by cnpj).

The commands for creating and restoring my default database.

> createdb teste01
>
> pg_restore -d dbGeralCardapio dados.backup

Vi um exemplo de excução de comandos no terminal assim:

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            run.exec(myCommand);
```

But for example ...

Before executing the commands I need to log in as root ... and enter the root password. How do I do this in java?

Comment: You should be able to do a CREATE DATABASE and a restore entirely by JDBC, with a special admin database user that has more rights (GRANT). Running as Linux root is not so advisable. And heavier.

Comment: https://www.jvmhost.com/articles/mysql-postgresql-dump-restore-java-jsp-code/ the way you want to do it. With JDBC you can slit the backup script and execute scripts as executeUpdate commands.

Comment: @JoopEggen create I get it ... can you give me a restore example?

Comment: I am not sure but if the dump or backup is an SQL script one can read the statements piecewise, and execute them seperately with executeUpdates, possible addBatch. I did such thing for another DB and a limited exec rights.